# App Identity for windows phone and windows store app

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1, windows-store-apps

I have the following challenge:

I publish a windows phone 8 app in the old windows phone developer portal and after a few months, I published a windows store app version in the old windows store developer portal(for windows store app). Both apps(windows phone 8 and windows store app) have the same name.

I have included an in-app product for the windows phone 8 app and was in the process of integrating it with my app when I noticed the windows phone 8 app has no app identity details on the developer portal but interestingly, the windows store app has an app identity.

I cannot go ahead with adding in-app products and integrating it into the windows phone 8 app. creating another reserved/unique name will go against the app name already in the store for download. I thought of removing or closing down the windows store app as a last solution, in order to reserve the name for the windows phone 8 app but I can't find any link or place to do that on the new developer platform. It will be nice if I can do that.

How do I go solving my challenges?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like the solution would be to merge the two apps in your (now unified) Windows Store developer account. That, or rename one of the apps to something else.

Either way, I think you need to get support involved. If you open a ticket with Microsoft Windows Developer Center support, they should be able to help you through the process.

Comment: Thanks Tobiah for the helpful advice. I have just finished chatting with a support representative and he escalated the issue to the engineering team. According to the support representative, he said it's a known issue.